# How to include a HTML file with node.js

Tags: html, node.js

So, I have a **server.js** file which loads an **index.html** file.

The question is, is there any way to import another html file in index.html.

To simplify, let's say I have an html file named **footer.html** and I want to import it in my **index.html**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inline send your html, or use 'fs' module to read html file and send it.

but it is better to use template engine, like ejs, handlebar, etc.

see this tutorial for more info
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to accomplish this.

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("index.html"); 
        });
        </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```